How to link existing Azure function to static web app using Terraform and FastAPI?
I am trying to link an existing Azure function to a static web app using Terraform and FastAPI. Provisioning and deployment in devops works fine, but the URL is not working properly.
When I request the function app URL https://func-***.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/ping, I get the following error:
{"code":400,"message":"Login not supported for provider azureStaticWebApps"}
When I request the API path in the static web app URL https://***.azurestaticapps.net/api/v1/ping, I get a 404 Not Found error.
I am not sure how to debug this, running the function locally works fine.
This is my Terraform code:
// Create a linux function app
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "this" {
  name                       = "func-${var.organization}-${var.application}-${var.environment}"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.this.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.this.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.function.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.function.primary_access_key

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  site_config {
    always_on                = true
    application_insights_key = azurerm_application_insights.this.instrumentation_key
    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.11"
    }
  }

  app_settings = {
    "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT" = "true"
    "URL_BASE"                       = "https://${azurerm_static_web_app.this.default_host_name}"
    "URL_BASE_API"                   = "https://${azurerm_static_web_app.this.default_host_name}/api"
  }

  tags = local.tags

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [auth_settings_v2]
  }
}

// Create static web app
resource "azurerm_static_web_app" "this" {
  name                = "app-${var.organization}-${var.application}-${var.environment}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.this.location
  sku_tier            = "Standard"
  sku_size            = "Standard"
}


// Register the function as API to the static web app
resource "azurerm_static_web_app_function_app_registration" "this" {
  static_web_app_id = azurerm_static_web_app.this.id
  function_app_id   = azurerm_linux_function_app.this.id
}

This is my function code:
import azure.functions as func
import fastapi

fastapi_app = fastapi.FastAPI(root_path="/api/v1")


@fastapi_app.get("/ping")
async def index():
    return "pong"


app = func.AsgiFunctionApp(
    app=fastapi_app, 
    http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS
)

The routePrefix in my host.json is an empty string. Any ideas on how to solve this?
EDIT: I figured out that when I deploy the function using AzureFunctionApp@2 in DevOps, it causes the link to break:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  inputs:
    connectedServiceNameARM: $(subscription)
    appType: 'functionAppLinux'
    appName: $(appName)
    runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.11'

It adds a bunch of environment variables in the function app which seem to break the link. However, when I use func azure functionapp publish $(appName) --python in a DevOps script step, the link works properly. Not sure if this is the 'correct' way to do it, because I feel like it should be working with AzureFunctionApp@2.

If you manually deploy with the same code using Terraform from your local machine, does the issue exist? If so, the problem could be with the configurations you set in the Terraform code.

@RMLiang thanks for your comment. I edited the post. I was provisioning Terraform locally in the first place, although the static web app and function app are deployed from devops. Seems like AzureFunctionApp@2 causes the problem.

Have you allowed the CORS origin from function app to access and link it to the static web app. @poklaassen

@Jahnavi I have not tried that, but I feel like that is not necessary since it works if I deploy with func azure functionapp publish, but does not if I use AzureFunctionApp@2, I recon due to environment variables (note edit).
